# Recover clipboard after shutdown or system failure/freeze

Tags: clipboard, clipboard-manager

My computer just froze and I was forced to reboot.

1. Is there any hope for recovering the text I had copied prior to the failure?  E.g. in logs
2. If not, what are my options for accessing the clipboard post-reboot in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I don't think so. If there was, Malicious Mallory could potentially take your old PC and scan your copy/paste history for important personal info. It makes sense that copy/paste history is not saved anywhere.

2) I used to have it setup, but got rid of it for the same reasons above. You can set it up by following this beautifully written guide: http://mpov.timmorgan.org/super-simple-clipboard-history-for-linux/

Sorry for your loss, but wish you luck for the future!

Comment: Honestly, if we're talking about Malicious Mallory, there's a whole lot of other stuff I'm more concerned about than my clipboard like browsing history, downloads folder, ssh keys, etc.  If you're really worried about Malicious Mallory, you'll have your storage encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Unity or Gnome, try the "diodan" package. If you are using KDE, try klipper, which appears to be included in the "plasma-workspace" package.

Either of these packages will capture clipboard contents and allow to to recall previous contents and even save and use the captured contents across reboots.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Clipboard Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator) which is actually a clipboard manager.

You can even customize the number of copied snippets it remembers.

The copied contents are persistent across reboot.